# what is the best way to switch from or exit from formFlow to Dialog in Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

Here is my Basic Code

[image]
The formFlow works fine and after checking the if condition ,it should go to the else part ,which it does, but in the else part the wrote this line of code

```
                   await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new AskMeAnything());
```

AskMeAnything is a class implementing Idialog. The problem is ,its again going/calling the formflow rather than jumping into the above mentioned dialog.

I read about IdialogStack but unable to understand how to remove the dialog on top of stack or something related to it.

i need help in moving to other dialog without looping into formflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first time you call `Conversation.SendAsync(...)` you actually create a root dialog for your conversation. Every consecutive call to the bot will still enter the controller but will be routed to the dialog at the top of the stack.

So when you call `Conversation.SendAsync(...)` for a second time you are actually trying to change the root dialog in the stack. I don't think this is possible and that's why your form is called again.

To solve this problem I would create a different dialog and make that dialog your root dialog. From this root dialog you can call your form and any other dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, just trying to understand u , lets say i created a root dilaog and called a sub dialog once, so the next time , root dialog will be on top of the stack and then the first sub dialog will be under it, so how would my new sub dialog called? .. any example or detailed explanation will help

Comment: no that's not right. when you start a sub-dialog from your root dialog with the "Call" or "Forward" method the sub-dialog is put on the top of the stack. All messages are from the controller directed to the top of the stack which will after this action be the sub-dialog. So the messages will no longer be handled in your root dialog. Once the dialog is finished you can call the "Done" method to end the dialog and the sub-dialog will then be poped from the stack, making the root-dialog the top of the stack.

Comment: Thanks Xeno - i will be more happy if u give a solution to my prob by seeing the above pic .. i am calling "makerootdialog" using Conversation.sendasync() which calls a formflow. once the formflow is completed , i am calling its .Done() method. upon new request it goes to else part ( as shown in fig ) where i am calling another dialog using Conversation.SendAsync(...) but its calling formflow again. can you assist me on this

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nNSUW5jP
Here is an example you should be able to use.
From the controller you call:
`await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());`

Comment: Hey Xeno , I got an error after using the code u provided like " Value cannot be null. Parameter name: wait " , for this i added a new await in "MainMessage", after which i am getting another error msg like " Activity Id cannot be null" . Here is the code First : [link](https://pastebin.com/eqV0F8wn) second: [link](https://pastebin.com/WVLjG24i)